# Cannot access eloquent relationship in laravel test

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I have the following relationship in `User` model and `UserLevel` model.

User:

```
public function user_level()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserLevel');
}
```

UserLevel:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

This works perfectly in Tinker as shown below:

[image]

But I can't seem to access the relationship in Laravel PHPUnit test. The following `die and dump` returns `null`:

```
class AddUserTest extends TestCase
{
  use DatabaseMigrations;

  /** @test */
  public function super_admin_can_view_add_user_form()
  {
    $super_admin_user = factory(User::class)->create([
      'username' => 'Test User 6',
      'user_level_id' => 7,
    ]);

    dd($super_admin_user->user_level);
  }
}
```

If I `dd` the `$super_admin_user`, it properly shows the created user. What am I doing wrong? How can I access the user_level in the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume, that in your model factory you create also related model, so if in your test you use:

```
$super_admin_user = factory(User::class)->create([
      'username' => 'Test User 6',
      'user_level_id' => 7,
    ]);
```

it won't work because. There is no UserLevel with id 7. So you should either create one in your test for example:

```
$user_level = factory(UserLevel::class)->create();
$super_admin_user = factory(User::class)->create([
      'username' => 'Test User 6',
      'user_level_id' => $user_level->id,
    ]);
```

or remove `user_level_id` from test completely:

```
$super_admin_user = factory(User::class)->create([
  'username' => 'Test User 6',
]);
```

(this is what you use in tinker)

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database-testing#writing-factories - section **Relations & Attribute Closures**